# Java SQL Update Query Not Working

Tags: java, mysql, javadb

I'm working on a simple java project that uses JavaDB and MySQL to introduce the use of databases. I'm trying to write a method for updating the scores of a game in a database.

```
public void setTeamsScore(int matchNumber, int hScore, int vScore) throws SQLException
{
   Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
   String sqlStatement = "UPDATE Matches " +
                         "SET HomeTeamScore = " + hScore + 
                         " WHERE " +
                         "MatchNumber = " + matchNumber;
   stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);

   sqlStatement = "UPDATE Matches " +
                  "SET VisitorTeamScore = " + vScore +
                  " WHERE " +
                  "MatchNumber = " + matchNumber;
   stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
}
```

I get no errors at runtime, and when I check the return value of the update statement, it returns 1 (which if I understand correctly, means that 1 row was updated in the database). However, the database doesn't get updated at all and keeps the same values from before.

At first, I thought that maybe auto-commit wasn't working, so I tried turning auto-commit off and using connection.comit() but that didn't solve the problem either.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to check if the Auto-commit is set to true or false .
if false then you have to commit the connection after the SQL execution .

```
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );
stmt.commit();
stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call both `stmt.execute(sql)` and `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)`

First check if your query returns a true result set or not.

`Boolean ret = stmt.execute(sqlStatement);`

Then update the records

`int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );`

If the data is still not updated check your connection object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried what you said and the data is still not updated... The console still says "Rows impacted : 1", but nothing changes. I have tried checking the connection but I'm using the same connection for other methods in the same class with no problem...

Comment: When I use `Boolean ret = stmt.execute(sqlStatement);`, it returns `false`. What does this mean?